# Cast to Embedded failed for value when using SubDocs in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I was using this on my user schema to be able to have a one to many relationships with the role collection but after I've tried to change it, I'm getting this error. I've searched for answers before but unfortunately, it doesn't answer my question.

Code before on the `UserSchema` :

```
  role: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: "Role",
    required: true
  }
```

Code after:

```
role: RoleSchema
```

Code on my `RoleSchema`:

```
const RoleSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    trim: true
  }
});

const Role = mongoose.model("Role", RoleSchema);

module.exports = {Role}
```

The complete error message through Postman:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "role": {
            "message": "Cast to Embedded failed for value \"b51c9619230f72627ed729e\" at path \"role\"",
            "name": "CastError",
            "stringValue": "\"b51c9619230f72627ed729e\"",
            "kind": "Embedded",
            "value": "b51c9619230f72627ed729e",
            "path": "role",
            "reason": {
                "message": "Tried to set nested object field `role` to primitive value `b51c9619230f72627ed729e` and strict mode is set to throw.",
                "name": "ObjectExpectedError",
                "path": "role"
            }
        }
    },
    "_message": "User validation failed",
    "message": "User validation failed: role: Cast to Embedded failed for value \"b51c9619230f72627ed729e\" at path \"role\"",
    "name": "ValidationError"
}
```

Comment: you are exporting your model from RoleSchema. You can not use like this.

Comment: I've tried having them on the same file, exporting/importing both model and schema or even calling it by Role.schema; none of those solutions changed anything, unfortunately.

Comment: Because, your older data are referenced by mongo `objectID` and now yoou are no more dependent on objectID. That's why your older data will throw error.

Comment: Do I need to remove all the data from the users or the roles collection?

Comment: You can write a migration script to migrate the data based on your new requirements. If it is just a home project then you can delete and generate new data.

Comment: I've deleted all the data and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: By starting the server do you get this error?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176649/discussion-between-hardik-shah-and-andre).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to pass `role : {"name" : "admin"}` as your schema expecting object along with String value.

This will store data like this:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("5b572805098d8a23a36cc62d"),
  "title" : "New Survey",
  "language" : {
    "name" : "EN",
    "_id" : ObjectId("5b572805098d8a23a36cc62e"),
    "ut" : 1532438230187.0,
    "ct" : 1532438230187.0
  },
  "ut" : 1532438230187.0,
  "ct" : 1532438230187.0,
}
```